# How to use JAXB to store an Array Class in a Class<?> field

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I would like to marshall/unmarshall a Java Object with a `class<?> datatype` field. This works well if the Class in known by the JAXB Context but it doesn't work to store a Java Array Class.

My Object :

`@XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public class MyClass {
        private Object value;
        private Class<?> datatype;
    }`

If I do: `c.setDatatype(Short.class);` it works.
If I do: `c.setDatatype(Short[][].class);`it stores `<datatype>[[Ljava.lang.Short;</datatype>` in the XML file, but the Datatype field is null when unmarshalled.

I added `Short[][].class` to the JAXBContext. This works if I use XStream.

I think I can make this work with a `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` to handle the array case. But is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: I think, the adapter, as you note, is the best way.